# How do i reduce my DP(Dynamic Programming) state?

Tags: c++, state, dynamic-programming

I am trying problem: http://www.spoj.com/problems/BUD13TLF/

The problem is with my DP state:
I have recursion for this as:
let **k**=space left,**visited[ ]** array to keep track of visited elements , array **a[ ]** represent w1,w2,..wn.   and function **int solve (k , visited[ ])** is my function that returns ans 
this is my function:

```
int solve(int k,vector<bool> vis){

    if(k<0)return 0;
    if(k==0)return 1;
    int ans=1;
    loop(i,n){
        if(!vis[i]){
            vis[i]=1;
            ans+=solve(k-a[i],vis)%MOD;
            vis[i]=0;int j;
            for(j=i+1;a[j]==a[i];j++);
            j--;
            i=j;
        }
    }
    if(ans!=1) ans--;
    return ans;
}
```

the problem is How Do I define my DP state because visited(vector/array) can be huge (max 2^100 possibilities if i choose bitmasks or bitsets)? also please comment on how can I represent a DP state if my DP state depends on whole array ?

Comment: yeah thats what i asking for, I have recursion but how do I decide dp state?

Comment: one who has downvoted plz tell me what wrong i am asking

Comment: Pass vector by reference instead of copy ?

Comment: @jarod42 I tried it,gives TLE and still need DP solution

Comment: BTW, you don't use dynamic programming here (you just use recursion). I think you have to find better algorithm that brute force.

Comment: Yes ,but that is my question ? I am unable to make a DP state

Comment: Why do you think DP should be used ?